# Unparseable time in Java with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime, time

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

edto.setDate(formatter.parse(startHrs.getText() + ":" + startMin.getText());
```

Hello, I'm trying to format my time into something like `12:08 PM` to add into sqlite as type `DATETIME`.  In my DTO class the corresponding time field is of `Date` type.

I am getting error for the above that such string is unparseable. Why is this.

Please note `startHrs` and `startMin` are two JTextFields Components taking in the value of Hours (12) and Minutes (08) respectively.

How can I successfully parse the date?

Errors:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12:12"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
```

Comment: Please post the error you have

Comment: I'd get rid of the `a` part of the format -  it doesn't seem like your `startMin` field includes the AM/PM part. You need to handle that differently, like using a radio box, or a 24h hour.

Comment: no it doesn't isnt it automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `dateformat` is `h:mm a` which does not match with `12:12`. It will match with `12:12 PM`.

Try -

```
edto.setDate(formatter.parse(startHrs.getText() + ":" + startMin.getText()+" PM");
```

I would suggest you to use `HH` instead of `h` which represent Hour in day (0-23) there you don't need  to predict `Am/pm marker`.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
edto.setDate(formatter.parse(startHrs.getText() + ":" + startMin.getText());
```

Comment: how do I make it automatic based on the input, don't really want it defined

Answer (score 2):

You need to add AM or PM

```
edto.setDate(formatter.parse(startHrs + ":" + startMin + " AM"));
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'a' to set up PM / AM - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Try parsing:

```
12:12 AM
```

Comment: automatic AM or PM? any idea

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

edto.setDate(formatter.parse(startHrs.getText() + ":" + startMin.getText());
```

In above code formatter string is hour:minute:am or pm but i can see as input you are only providing hour and minute which results in unparsable date. Either correct your parser format string or provide input in hour:minute:AM or hour:minute:PM format.